# SASS inheritance - omiting the base class

Tags: css, inheritance, sass

I can use this syntax for inheriting a class in SASS

**Code**

```
.message {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: green;
}
```

**Output**

```
.message, .success, .error, .warning {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  border-color: green;
}
```

I want to do something similar, whereby .message is omitted from the output

**Desired Output**

```
.success, .error, .warning {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  border-color: green;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using placeholder selector:

**SASS**

```
%message {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  @extend %message;
  border-color: green;
}

.error{
  @extend %message;
  border-color: red;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.success, .error {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  border-color: green;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

The problem is if you want *message* like a class, then you have to extend too:

```
.message{
  @extend %message;
}
```