# SaSS extend only properties

Tags: sass

Is is possible in SaSS to only extend the css properties of a class, and avoid rendering a concatenated classname:

```
.class_A {
    background-color: #f0f;
}

.class_B {
    color:#555;
    @extend class_A;
}
```

desired result:

```
.class_B {
    color:#555;
    background-color: #f0f;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SASS inheritance - omiting the base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520491/sass-inheritance-omiting-the-base-class)

Comment: Do you ever use, or want to use, `.class_A`?

Answer (score 1):

If you still need `.class_A` then you can do this

```
%bg-color {
  background-color: #f0f;
}
.class_A {
    @extend %bg-color;
}

.class_B {
    color:#555;
    @extend %bg-color;
}
```

Output CSS:

```
.class_A, .class_B {
  background-color: #f0f;
}

.class_B {
  color: #555;
}
```

If you don't need `.class_A` just use a variable:

```
$bg-color: #f0f;

.class_B {
    color:#555;
    background-color: $bg-color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, greatly appreciate it :-)